# "dead" tkinter windows after quitting

Tags: python, tkinter, systray

I have a script that creates a tray icon from where I call two different windows.

The tray icon library I'm using (infi.systray) creates a quit option automatically but if the windows are not closed they remain after quitting. They become non responsive and the app doesn't quit. What should I do to make the quit option destroy any window that is open?

This is my code:

````
```python
import time
import threading
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

makemestop=False

# functions that will be trigered by infi.systray need the variable that contains the SysTrayIcon object as a parameter
def callwin1(icon):
    win1()

def callwin2(icon):
    win2()

def win1():
    def win1bye():
        window1.destroy()

    window1=Tk()
    window1.title("Hi bruh this is window 1")
    window1.geometry("350x30+600+600")
    buttonwin1=ttk.Button(master=window1, text="Okay", command=win1bye)
    buttonwin1.pack()
    window1.mainloop()

def win2():
    def win2bye():
       window2.destroy()

    window2=Tk()
    window2.title("Sup money this is window 2")
    window2.geometry("350x30+0+0")
    buttonwin2=ttk.Button(master=window2, text="Okay", command=win2bye)
    buttonwin2.pack()
    window2.mainloop()

# the function to quit the program
def make_me_stop(icon):
    global makemestop
    makemestop=True
    my_x.join()
    print("I STOPPED!")

# This must go into another thread
def myloop():
    try:
        #while makemestop==False:
        while True:
            print("I'm doing something in the background")
            time.sleep(3)

            if makemestop==True:
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

# this is the main thread
if __name__=="__main__":
    my_x=threading.Thread(target=myloop)
    my_x.start()

    menu_options=(
            ("Options", None, callwin1),
            ("About", None, callwin2),
    )

    icon=SysTrayIcon("16.ico", "My icon title", menu_options, on_quit=make_me_stop)
    icon.start()
```
````

Comment: ***the windows are not closed***: Which `window` you are refering to?

Comment: Either of them. I want the script to close them when I call the quit option from the menu

Comment: You have to define `global window2`, this allows to call `window2.quit()` from inside `def make_me_stop`